# Linux display string between 2 words in sentance

Tags: linux, sed

So i am struggling a bit to cut only what i need from string.
For example i have the string "Hello world, how are you doing today?"

So i tried using SED

```
 sed -e 's/Hello\(.*\)doing/\1/'
```

Which does remove the **Hello** and **doing**, but leaves **today?**

And the end result is **world, how are you today?** and i need it to be **world, how are you**

Looking for further advise how to better do this.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove everything after `doing`, add `.*` after it in the pattern:

```
echo 'Hello world, how are you doing today?' | sed -e 's/Hello\(.*\)doing.*/\1/'
 world, how are you
```

Also note the leading space in the output. Add a space after `Hello` in the pattern if you want to remove it, as well.